# zsh condition on number results in bad pattern

Tags: if-statement, zsh

I have a function that I minified to debug but I cannot see the problem. Here is the minimal code to reproduce the issue:

```
#!/bin/zsh

ahead=1
if [[ "$ahead" -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "test"
else
    echo "testelse"
fi
```

I get from executing this script:

```
./test:4: bad pattern :[[ 1
```

I cannot understand where the problem is. If I test it with [tio.run](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P9fWVE/KTNPv6o4g4srMSM1McXWkCszTSE6WkFJBcxXUtDNS1UwUIiNtVYoyUjN41IAgtTkjHwFpZLU4hIlrtSc4lQ0QZCQElda5v//AA), it works!
If I copy paste it in console it also works.

If I remove the shebang I get:

`./test: line 2: [[ 1: command not found
testelse`

Comment: please provide the output of these commands: `/bin/zsh --version` and `ls -l /bin/zsh`

Comment: It works for me and it should work with your version of *zsh*. You may have a problem in your *zshrc*. And why do you have an error on line 5 whereas the *bad pattern* in on line 4?

Comment: The ouput of /bin/bash --version is `zsh 5.3.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)` and for ls -l /bin/bash its `-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 796256 Mar 21 10:39 /bin/zsh` as for the line its 4 not 5 (I removed local ahead)

Comment: Can't reproduce. !! Got the results `test` for this.

Comment: @2A-66-42 i didn't ask about `/bin/bash`, and it's very suspicious that your bash claims to be zsh.  in a system like that, all bets are off.

Comment: and, `[[ 1: command not found` makes it look like maybe you have some weird whitespace character between `[[` and ``"$ahead"``.

Comment: @justsomebody I meant /bin/zsh not /bin/bash (/bin/bash --version outputs `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really know how or why but as @justsomebody pointed out in the comments it was some kind of weird whitespace character between `[[` and `$ahead`. Might be vim or something else, if you have any clue what it could have been, it would be nice to know.

**Edit**: I will add that `altgr + space` creates the kind of character that leads to this situation.

Comment: Most probably a non break space. Maybe code copied from a web page, or like you said, an altgr + space will create this character on many keyboard layouts. For future reference, try to replace all white spaces. Or copy the text and paste it into any (online) hexeditor to see if the space is actually ascii code 20 or if is perhaps utf code C2A0 (non break space).

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same error where I put double quotes string in an already double quoted command in the .bashrc file. It was in a multi-line command and I didn't notice it at first.

Doesn't work:

```
alias my_command="echo "doublequoted string example no no""
```

Works:

```
alias my_command='echo "doublequoted string example yes yes"'
```